# How to stop a trashbin from stinking

Tags: cleaning, smell, air

Okay, so we have bin collection once a week. For clarity sake, this is what our bin looks like:

[image: Wheelie bin]

So basically, occasionally the bag wears out and we loosen it so that it gets thrown out when the garbage collection comes, leaving the bin empty. The bin continues to smell even when there isn't the bag (*or rubbish*) inside of it. It's even clean inside the bin, which ends up in me having to wash the bin out.

Are there any options to keep said bin "smelling nice" / "not stinking"? I'm thinking of a more permanent solution (removing the smell), not masking the smell. Would Baking Soda be the option of choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put food in the trash. Instead, flush down the toilet or use the disposal. Rinse out cans and containers before throwing in the trash.

Wash the bin out periodically. If you leave it sit, it will eventually air out, but it may help to wash out with a hose.

I would remove the big trash bag from the external bin. It serves only to prevent the bin from airing out. Do not throw anything into the bin that is not already in a trash bag or grocery bag. A bag in the bin itself is unnecessary.

When throwing small bags into the bin, insure they are tied.

Make sure to have the bin at the curb on time for weekly pick up.

I do not recommend baking soda or similar remedies. Once you stop whatever bad habits regarding the trash bin, putting an agent in the bin will not be necessary. Do things differently starting now and the smell will be gone in a few days.